# Direct2d command analog to OpenGL's SwapBuffers?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, c++builder, direct2d, c++builder-2010

What is Direct2d command analog to OpenGl's SwapBuffers? I am using this in a VCL environment such as Delphi and CPP Builder. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: None for Direct2d? Oh , well, I'll stick to OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do the equivalent in Direct2D. The simplest way is to create an ID2D1HwndRenderTarget. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371275(v=vs.85).aspx for details. You'll be interested in the D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES parameter. This has a D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS field, which can be set to different values depending on the behavior you want. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368144(v=vs.85).aspx for details. With this in place, the rough equivalent of SwapBuffers is ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw.

The other option is using Direct3D interop. In this case you create a DXGI surface render target. (I'd post a link to the docs, but I don't have enough StackOverflow reputation to post more than two hyperlinks. Google "ID2D1Factory::CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget" for the docs). This allows you to use Direct2D to issue 2D rendering commands to the surface, but then present using Direct3D/DXGI. This is more complicated but gives you more flexibility.